# 'firebase deploy' compilation error in storage.rules

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-hosting

I am trying to deploy the firebase app from [here](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat/tree/master/web) and I am following [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#0) tutorial. I would like to deploy my firebase app. However, when I enter

```
firebase deploy
```

I get an error. Here are my logs:

```
egaumbp:web gg$ firebase deploy

=== Deploying to 'friendlychat-6e4c3'...

i  deploying database, storage, hosting
i  storage: checking rules for compilation errors...

Error: Compilation error in storage.rules:

[E] 3:12 - Unexpected '<'.
egaumbp:web gg$
```

I am logged in, and I have version 3.0.0 of the firebase toolkit, and I am doing this from a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2012), on OSX EL Capitan Version 10.11.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of the examples in the getting started guide use a convention of `<placeholder>` where the developer needs to provide some additional information to make the example function. In the first example from [Understanding Firebase Storage Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/#authorization), the following code snippet is presented with the placeholder `<your-firebase-storage-bucket>`.

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/<your-firebase-storage-bucket>/o {
    // ... more rules ...
  } 
}
```

To fix the `Unexpected '<'` error in this case, replace the placeholder with `friendlychat-6e4c3.appspot.com` like so:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/friendlychat-6e4c3.appspot.com/o {
    // ... more rules ...
  } 
}
```

A detailed overview of the supported syntax and functions is available at [Learn to Secure Files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/secure-files#understand_rules). It's a good reference if you encounter more compilation errors.

Comment: am doing what u have mentioned in your answer to this friendly-chat-4bd7c.appspot.com/o but still am getting the same error any idea